# Is there an Eslint rule that can be used to enforce that the import statements for default exports are named the same as the original definition?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, es6-modules

I need an Eslint rule that can be used to enforce that the import statements for default exports are named the same as the original definition.

I have the following rules in my eslintrc.json:

```
"rules": {
    "import/no-anonymous-default-export": "error",
    "import/no-named-as-default": "error"
}
```

and I have a file where I need to use default export, foo.ts:

```
const foo = "foo";
export default foo;
```

and I want to use it somewhere else, a test for example, foo.test.ts:

```
import bar from "./foo";

describe("foo", () => {
    it("equals foo", () => {
        expect(bar).toBe("foo");
    });
});
```

This works and `npx eslint .` doesn't report any errors.
Should these rules report this? If yes, then what could I be doing wrong? If not, then are there any other rules I can use?
Note: Eslint does report if I try to export something without assigning it first, so at least that works I suppose.

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/issues/1041) and [this PR](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/pull/1143). It's been in the works for years but never made it in.

Comment: There is no "original definition" in your example. If you use `export default …;` with an expression, the local name is `*default*`; just like when you write `export default "foo";`. You would need to use `export { foo as default }` to actually export the `foo` variable itself.

Comment: Thanks both for your answers. I tried using `export { foo as default }` and I have the same issue. It seems from the issue/PR link that this won't be easy to solve, but I would still appreciate any further advice on how to improve this situation.